# PHP MySQL fetch result is cached and needs a page refresh.

Tags: php, mysql, caching, refresh, fetch

I have a created a MySQL Database and added a table to it (table name is "entries"). Also I created a page "all-entries.php" and connected this page to the database in order to fetch the data. 
Everything works fine except one thing... When I add new entry to the database table and go to "all-entries.php", it doesn't show the additions that I just added. In order to get it to show latest updates, I need to either clear the cache of my browser or hit the reload button on my browser. What could be causing this problem?

Here is the code for "all-entries.php" page:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entries");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that the mysql_* extension that you've used was **removed** from PHP version 7?

Comment: Hey, yes I am. But I am using php 5.4 (Not my choice btw :P)

Comment: I found a solution. I just had to add this line of code to prevent the page from caching. 
`header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.` I still dont understand why it was caching so much though. I'd appreciate if someone explained this to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Great question. I was dealing with the exact same issue. I too discovered that by using `header("cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");` would get rid of the problem.

However, I ran into an issue with that, primarily being that my page loaded extremely slowly. What I found out was that I was not adding one of the most basic pieces of code at the end of my file.

```
mysqli_free_result($dbconn);
```

What happens when you don't use that piece of code is that the result is stored in memory. Try adding it at the end of your script to free the result. When I started using it, my images, CSS, and java were still cached, but I returned to most up to date query each time I loaded the page.

Hope this helps and I apologize its not the most well-worded answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to refresh the page, obiously.
are you working on ajax ? in case of ajax you don't need to reload the page, data will be updated without reloading the page.

please provide a little more information, so that we can provide answers and correct info. :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for a quick response. So here is the scenario:
I added a new entry to the table. I go to php myAdmin and I can see it entry there (To make sure that the problem is not in addition part). 
Now when I open "all-entries.php" page, the entry I just added is not there. I have to refresh the page again to make it show up. 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Or the other option is, after I add the new entry to the table, I clear my browser cache (before even loading "all-entries.php" page), and then load "all-entries.php", and I can see the new entry there.  

Ideally, I want it to show the entry I added the first time I open  "all-entries.php" (so that I dont have to reload it).

Comment: you want that whenever you change data in database . it is automatically shows up on the page? without you being reloading it ? , if that is the case, then I suggest you use ajax, 
do a little research on ajax, its not tough :)

Comment: No, I am okay with reloading page. But in this situation, I need to reload it twice to get it to show my additions. So basically, after I add the entry and I load the all-entries.php page, I want to see latest additions as well. However, now in order to see them, I need to load all-entries.php, and then reload it again. Looks like old sql fetch is cacher or something. Is that possible?

Comment: that's weird , ..
I am using the same sql query  :) and it works fine(OLD but not  obsolete) .. it will be deprecated soon but it still works correctly. will need to see your both the files in order to see what's going wrong. if you can upload your complete php code, that might help me getting to right answer.

Comment: I found a solution. I just had to add this line of code to prevent the page from caching. 
`header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.`
I still dont understand why it was caching so much though.

Comment: hahaha . anyways :) you can always find solution if you keep looking for it :) well done !